# connect multiple programs to one server with sockets, c

Tags: c, sockets

I need to make a server and a client to a simple chat. The server must to have threads to keep listening all clients and must send a message received to everyone. The server must have 2 threads to keep listening the socket for new messages and to read the message from keyboard and send it to the server. My problem is: how to make multiple connections to the server? I was thinking in use multiples sockets, one for each client, and the clients would try to connect with each port until some works, but it doesn't give error if the socket already has a connection in a port as I tough. Does someone has some tips? I need to use TCP.

EDIT: My problem isn't in the server, my problem is in the client. What I did (or tried, at least, I'm not sure if it's right) was make the main in the server create a thread to listen a socket. When there is a connection, this thread take care of that socket and the main create another thread to take care of other socket with other port. The problem is: how can I detect in the client that a port is already in use and I need to connect in the socket of the next port?

And sory for the bad English.

Comment: Why -2? What I did wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  The reasons for down-voting this are probably 'this has been asked before' and 'this can easily be searched on the web'. Some people are more impatient with questions like this than others.

Comment: I searched about my problem in the net and here, but couldn't  find anything that could help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Client-side

Working from memory, for a TCP socket, the client simply uses [`socket()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) and 
[`connect()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html), specifying the server IP address and port number.  The `connect()` automatically assigns you a local port; you don't have to do anything special.

#### Server-side

<sup>*A first edition of the question seemed to be discussing the server-side issues*</sup>

When the server runs, it uses [`listen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html) on a well-known socket (with a well-known port number).  It then goes into a loop with the server blocking on [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) which creates a new socket file descriptor for the new incoming connection, separate from the listening socket file descriptor.

```
Server

socket()
   |
bind()
   |
listen()
   |
   +<----+
   |     |
accept() |
   |     |
process  |
   |     |
   +-----+
```

You might have an iterative server that loops after processing the request itself, but more the server will usually either fork a new process or start a new thread to handle the accepted connection.

See also [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), amongst other options.

Comment: "When the system detects a new connection, the `listen()` returns" is not true. `listen()` is not a blocking function. It always returns immediately once the socket has been put into a listening state. It is `accept()` that does not return until a new client has connected, if you use it in blocking mode (the default), that is. If you use it in non-blocking mode, then it always returns immediately, letting you know whether a new client has connected, or whether the wait would block and needs to be called again.

Comment: "which has an ephemeral port number that's unique" is also not true. An accepted client socket on the server side uses the server's listening IP/Port and the client's outbound IP/Port.  The client port may be ephemeral on the client side, but certainly not on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a threaded TCP server, the standard way is two have on thread that listen for connections and accept clients, then start a new thread for each accepted client. You can find multiple examples on the net, some quick google search gave me that: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/